# java - I can't access to find R.id.title1 or R.id.title2

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to access `TextView` and `ImageView` but id's are not in the list
 I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yK8RtB6aXC4 on you tube 
here is my `Xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

      <TextView

        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Sub Title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="subtitle"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />



</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Class code

```
package com.demo.adapter;

import java.util.List;

import com.demo.modles.Navigation;
import com.example.madrobo.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NavigationListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Navigation>{
Context context;
int resLayout;
List<Navigation> navigationlist;
    public NavigationListAdapter(Context context, int resLayout,
            List<Navigation> navigationlist) {
        super(context, resLayout, navigationlist);
        this.context=context;
        this.resLayout=resLayout;
        this.navigationlist=navigationlist;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v=View.inflate(context, resLayout, null);

        TextView textview1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id);

        return v;
    }

}
```

NAvigation Class

```
package com.demo.modles;

public class Navigation {

    private String title;
    private String subTitle;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getSubTitle() {
        return subTitle;
    }
    public void setSubTitle(String subTitle) {
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
    }
    public int getResIcon() {
        return resIcon;
    }
    public void setResIcon(int resIcon) {
        this.resIcon = resIcon;
    }
    public Navigation(String title, String subTitle, int resIcon) {
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.subTitle = subTitle;
        this.resIcon = resIcon;
    }
    private int resIcon;


}
```

[here is my packages picture Please see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXbwA.png)

Comment: dear i already try TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title1); still not working

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error? What is it?

Comment: no error but i can't access id.title1

Comment: after type title1(ERROR) create field 'title' int type id

Comment: Please explain what "I can't access `id.title1`" means. What exactly is not going the way you expect it to?

Comment: when you write (R.id.) open a list which have all the id's shown i have also show some id's but excepts my above xml file which have title1 id title2 id and also home_icon id

Answer (score 0):

The R class could cause an error, but when it causes an error it shows the error as all of the "R." statements are red in colour.

You can check 2 more things.
**1) Android Power Save Mode**
Have a look at the screenshot below. There it specifies Android Studio Power Save Mode. If it is checked you face the same problem as the ids are not accessible as it turns off the intellisense for Android Studio for enhancing user performance.

To access the Android Power Save Mode you need to Left Click on the bottom right corner small android icon as shown in the image below.
[image: Android Power Save Mode]

Please uncheck (Power Save Mode) and keep the Import popup checked as in image below.[image: Android Power Save Mode turned Off]

**2) Shortcut to Access ids**
If you are not able to access the ids instantly you could press `"Ctrl + Space"` at once so that the list appears if it is not appearing due to any other reason.

Comment: In Eclipse go to
`Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced `and there check boxes labeled `"Java Proposals"` then press `Apply`

Comment: Why dont you switch to Android Studio? It is good for Android Development and it is official IDE from Google for Android. It includes all your packages and has much better IntelliSense than others.

Comment: i will checked the option Java Proposal but still not access to id's

Comment: i am student in my school lab only Eclipse available

Comment: Try manually typing in the ids if intellisense does not work, then build it and run. This is to detect the issue is with your editor or your code.

Comment: when i try to manually enter the id get (ERROR) title1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: remove your `import com.example.madrobo.R;` statement.  Clean the project.<br/> Build the project, check whether it asks for the same id issue when you manually type in the ids. Then clean Eclipse caches. Then run the project and check for any errors.

Comment: now i have error on all files where the R object use

Comment: also error on import com.example.madrobo.R; on other files

Comment: that tutorial itself gives you some instruction about your issue i believe. press Ctrl + Shift + O to fix import auto (Eclipse IDE)

Answer (score -1):

You are importing a R class from an other package than your java is in. You don't have to import a R class, because it is automaticly generated.

Comment: i don't understand my problem is still there

Comment: I don't have to import because its in the same package.